# How to find this element using Selenium? The link has a .do ending

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am try to locate and click the link using selenium. 
The html is as follows:

```
<a href="gotoOpenOrders.do?PID=bestbuy">21</a>
```

On the webpage, the number 21 appears as a hyperlink and will bring to next page when clicked.

I tried using xpath to a href and partial link text to "21" but it didn't work.
Any ideas on how to click that link?

Comment: what's the locator used? `//a[normalize-space(text())='21']`

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand. Can you clarify what you are asking

Comment: Have you tried with xpath that I mentioned in the comment? Try it and also share the xpath that you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `contains` sample usage:

```
//body[contains(@Attribute,'value')]
```

for you:

```
//a[contains(text(),'21')].click()
```

note:(it is normally written as "@Attribute" but, "text" is not exactly "Attribute" so "@" is not used)

Comment: thank you so much!! it worked. I really appreciate your help.